# Jest beforeAll() share between multiple test files

Tags: jestjs

I have a Node.js project that I'm testing using Jest.  I have several test files that have the same setup requirement.  Previously, all these tests were in one file, so I just had a `beforeAll(...)` that performed the common setup.  Now, with the tests split into multiple files, it seems like I have to copy/paste that `beforeAll(...)` code into each of the files.  That seems inelegant - is there a better way to do this, ideally where I can just write my `beforeAll(...)`/setup logic once, and "require" it from multiple test files?  Note that there are other tests in my test suite that don't require this setup functionality, so I don't want to make *all* my tests run this setup (just a particular subset of test files).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you're using Jest >=20, you might want to look into creating a custom `jest-environment` for the tests that require this common setup. This would be a module that extends either `jest-environment-node` or `jest-environment-jsdom`, and implements `async setup()`, `async teardown()`, and `async runScript()` to do this setup work.

You can then add a `@jest-environment my-custom-env` directive to those files that require this setup.

See the Jest config docs for [`testEnvironment`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string) for details on how to set this up; there's a simple example there.

Comment: One caveat: we recently tried to use an environment to do some initialization of a common node module, but realized that the require cache is reset between running the environment before steps and running test code. The module in question initialized some module-local vars and those got wiped after the env setup ran, so it didn't work out. This was a smell that our singleton module was poorly designed.

Comment: This doesn't work across files though. Even per their own documentation, `Note: TestEnvironment is sandboxed. Each test suite will trigger setup/teardown in their own TestEnvironment.`

Comment: I think prefer the below approaches - just a lot easier to follow

Answer (score 16):

I am using a simple ["test hooks"](https://kristiandupont.medium.com/test-hooks-be89b760d2db) pattern for this:

```js
// This function wraps beforeAll and afterAll into a single RAII-like call.
// That makes the describe code further down easier to read and makes
// sure you don't forget the afterAll part. Can easily be shared between tests.
function useFakeServer() {
  let server;

  beforeAll(() => server = sinon.fakeServer.create());
  afterAll(() => server.restore());
  
  return () => server;
}

describe('Some scenario', () => {
  const getServer = useFakeServer();
  
  it('accesses the server', () => {
    const server = getServer();
    // Test as you normally would..
    expect(server.requests[0]. /* ... */);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 14):

If you need a script to run before all your test files, you can use `globalSetup`

> This option allows the use of a custom global setup module which exports an async function that is triggered once before all test suites.

in your `jest.config.js`

```js
//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  testTimeout: 20000,
  globalSetup: "./setup.js"
};
```

then create a file named `setup.js`

```js
// setup.js
module.exports = async () => {
    
    console.log("I'll be called first before any test cases run");
    //add in what you need to do here

};
```

[Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#globalsetup-string)

Comment: It can only achieve one criteria is calling first before any test cases run, it couldn't be accessed by other test files.

Answer (score 10):

Create a function somewhere like so:

```js
export function setupBeforeAndAfter(putParamsHereIfYouHaveAny) {
  beforeAll(() => shared-before-all-code);
  afterAll(() => shared-after-all-code);
  beforeEach(() => shared-before-each-code);
  afterEach(() => shared-after-each-code);
}
```

Then just call it wherever you would otherwise have manually written these functions:

```js
describe('My test', () => {
  setupBeforeAndAfter(putParamsHereIfYouHaveAny)

  it('is amazing', () => {
    // Stuff in setupBeforeAndAfter() will run before/after this test as appropriate
  })
})
```

Answer (score 7):

You can move your `beforeAll` logic into one file and reference it in jest.config.js `setupFilesAfterEnv` section:

```js
module.exports = {
...
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/testHelper.ts'],
...
}
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array

Comment: This is before each test file, not shared between test files