# How to write simple Jest preset

Tags: javascript, jestjs, preset

How to write own Jest preset with common `beforeAll` and `afterAll`?

I'm quite confused, seems that there is no related documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest beforeAll() share between multiple test files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997652/jest-beforeall-share-between-multiple-test-files)

Answer (score 0):

There is the environment that you can extend this way:

JEST config:

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: './suites/future/jest.myEnv.js',
};
```

The `jest.myEnv.js`:

```
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');

const start = async () => {
    console.log('START');
};

const stop = async () => {
    console.log('STOP');
};

class TestEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
    constructor(config) {
        super(config);
    }

    async setup() {
        await super.setup();
        await start();
    }

    async teardown() {
        await stop();
        await super.teardown();
    }

    runScript(script) {
        return super.runScript(script);
    }
}

module.exports = TestEnvironment;
```